# Regex - turning one long string of directories in a list - separating based on file extensions

Tags: php, regex

I have a php script that will be returning a long string of merged file locations, something like this:

```
/test/a/order_for_802ToyotaScion_8TVT13404_175603.zip/test/a/moo.rar/
```

I don't know if the files are going to be .rar or .zip, so i need to account for both.  What regex expression can I use to turn a long string into an array of individual paths?

I've started it with the following, but it only returns the first one:

```
((?<Directory>[^\/]+)\/(?<Name>[^/]+(?<Extension>\.rar|\.zip)))+
```

Comment: Your expression seems to work, see [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/tN3dP8). Note that you need to use `preg_match_all()` instead of `preg_match()`. I've got one question thought: Do you want the path and the extension in a separate array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for just zip and rar in the simplest form:

```
preg_match_all('/.*?(\.zip|\.rar)/', $string, $m);
print_r($m[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't even think about that approach.